# Convergence of a sequence of partial binomial sums

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have a sequence

$$a_n = (1-p)^n \sum_{\frac{n}{2}\le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^k.$$

I want to show that $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ if $0\le p < \frac{1}{2}$. Here's a plot of the sequence for $p=\frac{1}{3}$:

[image: plot of a_n]

---

Failed attempt:

$$\begin{align}
(1-p)^n \sum_{\frac{n}{2}\le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^k <& (1-p)^n \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k \text{ for } n\ge 1\\
=& (1-p)^n \left(1+\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^n = 1.
\end{align}$$

My hope here was to end up with something like $0.99^n$ in that last step so I could argue that since $a_n<0.99^n$ and $0.99^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to\infty$. Unfortunately it came out to 1, not $0.99^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a probability question in disguise. Let $X$ be a binomial$(n,p)$ random variable, 
so $X$ has mean $\mu=np$ and variance $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$. 
We can write your sum as $a_n=P(X\geq n/2)$, and by [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) we get
$$a_n\leq P\left(|X-\mu|\geq n(1/2-p)\right)\leq {\sigma^2\over n^2(1/2-p)^2}={p(1-p)\over n(1/2-p)^2}.$$ 
This clearly goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.

You could reverse engineer this proof to eliminate the probability, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Looking back at my class notes, it seems my professor invoked a form of Chebyshev's inequality a few times without referring to it by name. It's nice to know what it's called.

Comment: @Snowball Glad to be of help.